# Agricola: Traveling Player?

Tags: agricola

What the heck is the "Traveling Player" space for in Agricola (family game)? Besides gaining the food there, is there anything else significant about that space?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Traveling Players only becomes *really* relevant in the full game, when players' Occupations and Minor Improvements may trigger off using it.

So why is it still there in the family game, you ask?  Well, Agricola is a pretty tough game for newbies to "grok" on the first play, or even the first few plays.  The last thing you want is for them to have three Begging cards by the end of the second harvest, and vow never to play this stupid game again!

By having multiple spaces that just contain food piling up, even the least clued-up player has an obvious way of saving his family from grim starvation at the end of the harvest rounds.  And that's good.  Once they get a bit more experienced, they will turn their noses up at such an inefficient way of turning actions into food... but's that another story, for a later day!

Answer (score 8):

In the family game, it is just a food stockpile, and has no other significance.

I think your question stems from the name of the action. Like all other actions, the name 'Traveling Players' refers to how your family member spends their time. As opposed to fishing, collecting wood or planting a field, your family member works in a band of traveling players. That is, acrobats, actors in a *play*, jugglers and other various performers. It has nothing to do with the 'players' of the game.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**,

As in the regular versions, **Traveling Players** accumulates 1 food a turn.

Unlike the regular version, there are no occupations or minor improvements to play to gain a greater advantage from that space.